# matplotlib tick labels not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two sets of data:

```
Y = [0.8, 0.9, 0.5, 0.4…0.6]
X = [16,17,18,19…..216]
plt.plot(Y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(X), max(X)+1, 10))
```

Which gives:

[image]

I was trying to plot this but since there is >200 points on the X axis I wanted to display the X-ticks only every 10.

But now instead of the X axis starting at 16 it starts at 0 with first label appearing at 16 though its not the correct corresponding Y value.

How can I plot X, starting at 16, stepping every 10 points starting at 16 going till 216 every 10 such as 16/26/36/46...

Thank you

Comment: you should be doing `plot(X, Y)` (just like in my example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really cumbersome/confusing to use the `pyplot` interface for this stuff. I would interact with an Axes object directly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3))
xtickslocs = np.arange(16, 217, step=10)
#ax.plot(x_data, y_data, ...)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(xtickslocs))
ax.set_xlim(left=-5, right=225) # change this to suite your needs
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Comment: No this is not quite what I wanted. Sorry. I want the X axis to start at 16and go till 216, stepping every 10. What you have given is what I am getting right now.

Comment: @user3456863, be more explicit. Do you want labels at 20, 30, ... , 210? Show a version of your code that runs, the output it provides, and be clear about what you want changed.

Comment: plt.plot(Y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(nativeX), max(nativeX)+1, 10))
plt.show()  The X and Y arrays are as I said above. Y values are all between 0.0 and 1.0. X starts at 16 and goes till 216. I want the X tick labels to go 16/26/36/46…etc.

Comment: @user3456863 edit your question to include that make sure that it's runnable. Include a screen shot of your plot.

Comment: Sorry I cannot add pictures. I don't have 10 points in reputation to add pictures. I tried, I promise you but website won't allow me. Thank you.  The plot is like yours but I want 16 to be next to the 0.0 of the Y axis

Comment: @user3456863 you can post a link to imgur (and I can embed it)

Comment: @user3456863 you really should edit your question with clarifications and additional information instead of flooding with comments. Point is, use `plt.plot(X, Y)` like I did.

Comment: Thank you-you are right, I should do plot(X, Y) as you suggested. Thanks a lot, Paul.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you should use 2 arrays for xticks the first is where you want to put your labels and the second is the labels itself.

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(16, 216, step=10), np.arange(16, 216, step=10))
```